# What if there are multiple rename candidates under git rename-threshold

Tags: git

`git merge -Xrename-threshold=xx`

what if xx is low (5%) and there are more than one candidate to pick?

Would git stop when there are more than one candidate, or it will just pick the "best matched" one?

Comment: It behaves exactly as it does if the rename threshold is the default, it uses the best match.

Answer (score 1):

It will choose the best match.

Its similar to the `git diff -M`

> When used with -M, a totally-rewritten file is also considered as the source of a rename (usually -M only considers a file that disappeared as the source of a rename), and the number n controls this aspect of the -B option (`defaults to 50%`).
>
> -B20% specifies that a change with addition and deletion compared to `20% or more of the file’s size are eligible for being picked up` as a possible source of a rename to another file.